# Is it possible to add decimals together within a JSP forEach loop?

Tags: jsp, foreach, jstl

I am puzzling if it is possible to add decimal values which I get from a stored procedure together and get all decimals within the loop added together as one value.

For example:

```
<c:forEach var="row" items="${ aStoredProcedure }">
<fmt:formatNumber value="${ row.decimalNumber }"pattern="#,##0.00"/>
<br>
</c:forEach>
```

This prints out the values of each decimalNumber of each row onto their own lines in the form of common currency. I need a way to get all these decimalNumbers added together with each other, and I only need the final sum of them all. Can this be accomplished in JSP? any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *can* be accomplished in JSP as follows,

```
<c:set var="total" value="0.0" />
<c:forEach items="${aStoredProcedure}" var="row">
    <c:set var="total" value="${total + row.decimalNumber}" />
</c:forEach>
<fmt:formatNumber value="${total}" pattern="#,##0.00" />
```

but it is not the recommended way at all. The `<c:forEach>` is here not outputting anything, but basically performing business logic. Business logic belongs in the front controller, which is usually a servlet. Therein you have all the freedom to write Java code to prepare exactly the data (the model) the JSP (the view) needs.

Comment: thanks for the fast reply, that was just what I was looking for :) This will be my temporary solution, until I have time to dive deeper into my controller java class.